# Is there a marketplace site which sells features / compoents / code for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've been trying to get some features developed for my app which I don't have time to develop myself. And I wondered if there was a site / market place where I could buy plugins / components / features ?

Don't know what the terminology is plugins ?

Comment: if you have well defined requirements I think you should be more specific about what piece of functionality you'ld like to cover with third part libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of one which is run by Oliver Drobnik:
[Parts Store @ Cocoanetics](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/parts-store/)

It's also worthwhile looking at open source solutions. A good starting point is [Github](https://github.com/) and [Google](http://www.google.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I have written an article discussing the concept of a marketplace for app code components. It lists a few existing resources:

http://appsynth.net/blog/item/10-is-there-a-market-in-mobile-for-off-the-shelf-code?.html